# How to check if my app has sent request to a certain endpoint between x period of time?

Tags: reactjs, web, browser

The current react project I'm working on involves adding and removing data from firebase. The problem is, when a user creates and deletes simultaneously(maybe because of some spelling mistake), then the deletion request does not succeed because it was made while the creation request was still being processed. So, I will have to determine whether the app is still waiting for the creation response to come back. In which case, I will proceed with the delete request. If not, then I will give a certain amount of interval before the deletion request may proceed. As you might probably guess, I will have to know whether my app is already awaiting for a response for some action that the user might've taken and only after that I can determine if or how I might proceed with other requests. How do achieve this? How can I know if my app is already processing a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set the state (or even better, redux store) to notify your app that it' awaiting a response.

Something like:

```
makeRequest() {
    this.setState({waiting: true});
    const that = this;

    fetch('your/uri')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          //some actions

          that.setState({waiting: false});
      }
}
```